# Automatically style raster files

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm interested in using QGIS to analyze political results from previous elections. I'm comparing the performance of two political parties by precinct, so my data range could potentially go from -50% (one party wins every vote) to +50% (the other party wins every vote). However, because of the way that the raster works in QGIS, it's assigning each number incorrectly. A value of 0% (both parties tied on votes) should get the white value that is given to 21.73% in the first image. A possible solution would be to manually add each value in between, as can be seen in the second image, but that would take forever.

Does anyone know a way to add the other potential values faster?

I want to save the whole range as a style so I can apply this analysis to other races, not just the one I'm doing right now too.

Look at attached images to see what I mean.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: It seems difficult to automatically classify this. However, if you create a division, right-click the layer, copy the style, and paste it into another raster, the division you created will be applied as it is.

Comment: Do it manual once, then copy & paste. Further, you may add a default style for loaded raster layers. If you add all your data in one step, they'll be styled automatically. I also don't see how this is outside of QGIS intended functions.

Comment: Is this *definitely* a raster? Normally I'd expect election results to be in polygons, and the screenshots look more like the way QGIS displays polygon symbology. When I look at *raster symbology*, I get to choose "Render type" out of "Multiband Color," "Paletted/Unique values", "Singleband gray", "Singleband pseudocolor", "Hillshade" and "Contours". When I look at *polygon symbology*, I choose from "No symbols", "Single Symbol", "Categorized", "Graduated", "Rule-based", "Merged Features", "Inverted Polygons", "2.5 D" and "Embedded Symbols". This does affect how you choose the divisions.